# my str_to_date in mysql is returning null

Tags: mysql, string

I ran this statement in mysql and it returns null on every row:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Fri, 22 Jun 2012 03:35:24 +0000', '%a, %e %b %Y %H:%i:%s %%%%%%%%%%') FROm t2;
```

I don't know the right specifier for the `+0000`.  What should it be?

Comment: From the MySQL manual: ["For the specifiers that can be used in format, see the DATE_FORMAT() function description."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The +0000 is a time zone offset.

mySQL doesn't understand the concept of time zones, and apparently neither does `STR_TO_DATE`:  [the list of date/time format placeholders](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) doesn't mention time zones at all.

If you expect dates from varying time zones, this doesn't seem solvable with the help of mySQL only. You would have to preprocess the date elsewhere to turn it into one that is *always* UTC (or your local time zone, whatever applies), or if it already is always UTC, ManseUK's suggestion (adding `+0000` to your format string so mySQL ignores it) should work.

Comment: deleted my answer when i read your comment - its probably a bad idea to ignore it ...

Comment: +1 Always use UTC when using MySQL and set the timezone via the application.